# how to parse two column in string in one cycle?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have a string like this. I want to put the second row in an array(3,9,10,11...), and the third(5,8,4,3...) in an array

```
C8|   3|   5|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|   9|   8|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|  10|   4|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|  11|   3|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|  12|   0|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|  13|   0|  0|     |  0|1|  
C8|  14|   0|  0|     |  0|1|
```

This method originally parsed numbers by rows. now i have columns..
How to do this in this Parse method? I am trying for hours, i dont know what to do.

The Add method waits 2 integer. int secondNumberFinal, int thirdNumberFinal

```
private Parse(string lines)
{
        const int secondColumn = 1;
        const int thirdColum = 2;

        var secondNumbers = lines[secondColumn].Split('\n'); // i have to split by new line, right?
        var thirdNumbers = lines[thirdColum].Split('\n'); // i have to split by new line, right?

        var res = new Collection();

        for (var i = 0; i < secondNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var secondNumberFinal = Int32.Parse(secondNumbers[i]);
                var thirdNumberFinal = Int32.Parse(thirdNumbers[i]);

                res.Add(secondNumberFinal, thirdNumberFinal);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: Loop each line. Split on `|`. Add second split (index 1) to an array/list. Add third split (index 2) to an array/list. After the loop you will have your 2 arrays/lists.

Comment: If the original is a single string, then split once on newline to produce an array of string. Parse each of the new string by splitting on | & select the second & third values.

Answer (score 1):

Below piece of code should do it for you. The logic is simple: Split the array with '\n' (please check if you need "\r\n" or some other line ending format) and then split with '|'. Returning the data as an IEnumerable of Tuple will provide flexibility and Lazy execution both. You can convert that into a List at the caller if you so desire using the `Enumerable.ToList` extension method

It uses LINQ (`Select`), instead of `foreach` loops due to its elegance in this situation

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Parse(string lines) {
    const int secondColumn = 1;
    const int thirdColum = 2;

    return lines.Split('\n')
        .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
        .Select(items => Tuple.Create(int.Parse(items[secondColumn]), int.Parse(items[thirdColum])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original is a single string, then split once on newline to produce an array of string. Parse each of the new string by splitting on | & select the second & third values.

Partially rewriting your method for you :

```
private Parse(string lines)
{
  const int secondColumn = 1;
  const int thirdColum = 2;

  string [] arrlines = lines.Split('\r');
  foreach (string line in arrlines)
  {
    string [] numbers = line.Split('|');

    var secondNumberFinal = Int32.Parse(numbers[secondNumbers]);
    var thirdNumberFinal = Int32.Parse(numbers[thirdNumbers]);

    // Whatever you want to do with them here

  }
}
```